# how to restart a mouse hook?

Tags: winapi, hook

I have a mouse hook that (for an unknown reason) dies every now and then (not too often). Maybe it's because a mouse move is not processed fast enough by the hook at some point in time or smth. (can someone btw. tell me what the registry key is for the timeout value on Windows 7?), but whatever the reason, I'd like to know how I can restart the hook if it's dropped? I don't know how I'm supposed to detect when the hook dies and how to restart it..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registry key used:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\

LowLevelHooksTimeout=10000
```

Also change this and reboot your system.
 Windows 7 sadly has no provision for letting you know of hook drops. You may use mircosoft connect to report this.

Comment: That is a bit sad indeed. I guess changing the timeout will have to do. Do you happen to know what it is by default..? Cheers..